# How to do an ng-repeat that returns items of an array every 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to be able to return items from an array using ng-repeat.

What I want is some animated effect, where each item is displayed 3 seconds after the previous item.

Here is an example ng-repeat that return results after 3 seconds delay.
http://jsfiddle.net/98rbe9hc/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:delay_filter">
     <span>Name : {{phone.name}}</span>
     </li>
     </ul>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    var delayed = false;
    $scope.phones = [
        { name: 'Motorola' }, 
        { name: 'Nokia' },
        { name: 'Ericsson' }
    ];

    var delayInMilliseconds = 3000;
    var doneWaiting = false;
    $scope.delay_filter= function(item){
        return doneWaiting;
    };

    $timeout(function() {
        doneWaiting = true;
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
});
```

But what I want is for each item in array to be displayed 3 seconds after the previous item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="phone in phones" ng-if="count >= $index">
          <span>Name : {{phone.name}} {{count}} {{$index}}</span>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
        var delayed = false;
        $scope.phones = [
        { name: 'Motorola' }, 
        { name: 'Nokia' },
        { name: 'Ericsson' }
    ];

    var delayInMilliseconds = 3000;
    $scope.count = 0;

        $scope.cunter = $interval(function() {
            $scope.count+=1;
             if($scope.count >= $scope.phones.length){
              $interval.cancel($scope.cunter);
              console.log('end')
            }
        }, delayInMilliseconds);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Works well. Is it possible to stop the results after let say 20 results?

Comment: i think it will be dynamic depending on the length of scope.phones

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj to do that, add a second condtition to the if statement that cancels the interval thus `$scope.count >= $scope.phones.length || $scope.count == 20`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use an `$interval` so the filter repeats. Also, try adding a `doneWaiting` to each item so you check for that in your filter.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
    var delayed = false;
    $scope.phones = [
        { name: 'Motorola', doneWaiting: false }, 
        { name: 'Nokia', doneWaiting: false },
        { name: 'Samsung', doneWaiting: false },
        { name: 'Ericsson', doneWaiting: false }
    ];

    var delayInMilliseconds = 1000;
    $scope.delay_filter= function(item){
        return item.doneWaiting;
    };

    $scope.waitingInterval=$interval(function() {
        for (i = 0; i < $scope.phones.length; i++) { 
            if(!$scope.phones[i].doneWaiting){
                $scope.phones[i].doneWaiting = true;
                if(i==$scope.phones.length-1){
                    $interval.cancel($scope.waitingInterval);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }, delayInMilliseconds);
});
```